# Security For Firebird Database(s)

Tags: linux, encryption, centos, firebird

I am using firebird server 2.50. As far as I know there is no way to encrypt a database in Firebird. So how to secure the user data?

Manually encrypting all data before saving would cause trouble since i will not be able to use something like "starting with".

I use CentOs for Database servers. These servers are communicating with an Application Server which runs on Windows Server 2008.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encryption is one kind of several protection measures which can be done against potential adversaries. And there are other methods too. You need common security analysis before you go with decision whether to encrypt or not, and if not than what. You have to look who are adversaries, where they could hit, etc-etc-etc. Blind use of encryption may be waste of resource/time/money/etc. Do security analysis first.

Answer (score 1):

DB encryption is possible in version 3:

> With Firebird 3 comes the ability to encrypt data stored in database. Not all of the database file is encrypted:
>   just data, index and blob pages.
>   To make it possible to encrypt a database you need to obtain or write a database crypt plug-in.

Refer to [Firebird-3.0.0_Alpha1-ReleaseNotes](http://web.firebirdsql.org/download/prerelease/rlsnotes/Firebird-3.0.0_Alpha1-ReleaseNotes.pdf) for details